# Count occurrence and percentage of this occurrence

Tags: sql, count, percentage

I have a table ("gsheet.table") with one column ("column") containing "Yes" or "No".

- Column

  - Yes
  - No
  - Yes
  - No

I'd like a graph with two columns out of this table.

One counts the total number of occurrence of "Yes".
And the second shows the percentage of "Yes" compared to the total number of rows in the column.

id  Number  Percentage

- 1     * 2      * 50%
  (I don't know how to format this, but this is suppose to be a three columns table (expected result))

I'm very new to SQL and having a hard time doing this. Could you help me please?

Comment: You should add your sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an aggregation function, SUM(), over a CASE WHEN condition might do the trick here:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN column = "Yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes_,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN column = "Yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(column), 2) AS yes_percentage
FROM
  gsheet.table
```

You want to sum all the "Yes" as 1s, and then in the second column we just divide the total sum of ones for the total amount of rows in the column ( Yes / (Yes+No) ).

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I copied your code, I get 33 as yes_ (which sounds right) but I get 0 as yes_percentage. This might have to do with the fact that I have null values. I added a "WHERE column IS NOT null" in the end but this is not fixing it. Any idea?

Comment: Without any more hints I'm unable to help, since this approach is working to me. Could you share a sample of your data? And what database management system are you using?

Comment: try `SUM(CASE WHEN column = "Yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(column) AS yes_percentage` Note a `decimal` constant 1.0 otherwise most DBMSes will use integer arithmetic, so 33/100 = 0

Comment: Serg, your idea fixed it but with *100.0 instead of *1.0
`SUM(CASE WHEN column = "Yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(column) AS yes_percentage` I am wondering how I can round this to one decimal?

Comment: You can use the function ROUND() on top of the whole column. I'll edit my answer accordingly.